# Why this if section compiled to infinite loop?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

The C code below:

```
s32 load_string(char* string_new, char const* string_orign)
{
    StrEntry *entry = search_str_entry(string_orign);
    u8        buff_b[32];
    u16       buff_u[32];
    s32       read_size = 0;
    void     *str_file = 0;

    if (entry != 0){
        cmemclr(buff_b, 32);
        cmemclr(buff_u, 64);
        sprintf(&buff_b[0], "c:/data/%03d.str", entry->fid);
        c2w(&buff_u[0], &buff_b[0], 32);
        if (TryOpenFile(&str_file, buff_u, OPEN_MODE_READ) == 0){
            cmemclr(string_new, 256);
            TryReadFile(&read_size, str_file, entry->offset, string_new, entry->size);

            CloseFile(str_file);
            return (s32)entry->size;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The disassembly of this function:

```
  003464ac <load_string>:
  3464ac:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
  3464b0:   e1a00001    mov r0, r1
  3464b4:   ebffffda    bl  346424 <search_str_entry>
  3464b8:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
  3464bc:   08bd8010    popeq   {r4, pc}
  3464c0:   eafffffe    b   3464c0 <load_string+0x14>
```

We can see that the if section become a infinite loop, why?

I use -Os optimize option to compile this code.
The gcc version is

> gcc version 8.1.0 (devkitARM release 49).

Edit:

The cmemclr is a simple inline function:

```
static inline void cmemclr(void *buf, u32 size)
{
    u8 *dst = (u8*)buf;

    while(--size >= 0){
        dst[size] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `popeq` instruction will return the value in `r0` if the previous compare indicated that  it was equal to zero.  Essentially it's rewriting the code as `do { ... if (!search_str_entry(...)) return 0; } while(1);`.  This will save an instruction if it returns zero on the first attempt, break even if it returns zero on the second attempt, and take an extra instruction for each attempt after the second.  I'm not sure why gcc would decide that's a good trade-off, but in some cases it would be.

Comment: Please compile with `-S` to let the compiler generate assembly and show us that file.  It could be that the “infinite loop” is just an unfilled relocation.

Comment: @supercat: What second attempt? There is no loop in the source code. It is just an `if`, not a `while` or `for`. The compiler’s introduction of an infinite loop is indicative of some undefined behavior or hidden infinite loop (e.g., inside `cmemclr`) inside the then-clause of the `if`.

Comment: `StrEntry *entry`  **what** is StrEnrty? is it a man?

Comment: @wildplasser It's a struct.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'd misread the offset of the unconditional branch, which in turn caused me to think the outer `if` was a `while`.  Mea culpa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmemclr` is defective. Per an edit to the question, `cmemclr` is:

```
static inline void cmemclr(void *buf, u32 size)
{
    u8 *dst = (u8*)buf;

    while(--size >= 0){
        dst[size] = 0;
    }
}
```

Since `size` has type `u32`, which is presumably unsigned, `--size >= 0` is always true. The code enters an infinite loop.

## Answer Before Question Was Edited

One possibility is the assembly code you have shown is incomplete, and what currently appears as `b   3464c0` will be later resolved to another address.

Supposing the assembly is correct, and is not an incomplete placeholder awaiting further link resolution, the compiler has optimized the code inside the `if` statement to an infinite loop either because there is undefined behavior inside the statement (and hence an infinite loop is a permitted behavior) or because something in the statement performs an infinite loop.

Since you have not provided the implementations or specifications of the routines or macros used inside the `if` statement, further diagnosis is not available.